# ReadyPlayerMe Avatar Animation with ThreeJS, Kalidokit and MediaPipe

Tags: three.js, blender, virtual-reality, avatar, 3d-modelling

I am working on [ready player](https://readyplayer.me) avatar to animate realtime from camera using [Kalidokit](https://github.com/yeemachine/kalidokit) three Js in react. I am facing issues with arms that is not animating while i was successful to animate face, hips, spine.

I have seen that kalidokit works fine on .vrm 3D models while it face issue with .glb model that is provided by ready player. It could be possible that ready player generated avatar rigging is not as like vrm model. so help me if someone knows any solution or have worked on it.